# What football formations have been most prevalent in the English Premier League since 1992?

Tags: football, strategy, formations, english-premier-league

There are a handful of sites ([example](http://www.soccer-training-guide.com/soccer-formations.html)) discussing formations and their popularity, but few discuss what is popular in certain periods in specific leagues. What I'm looking for is an overview of what formations (i.e. 4-4-2, 4-3-3) were popular in the English football from 1992 to today.

Note: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_%28association_football%29#Classic_formations) provides general information about the use of specific formations, and occasionally cites specific matches.

Comment: In terms of a historical perspective of tactics used in various time periods, "Inverting the Pyramid: The History of Football Tactics" by Jonathan Wilson is a very good source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is certainly 4-4-2 as almost all teams in England were using that formation back then.

Of course the English Premier League didn't exist in the 1980s as it started in 1992, but I have assumed the question relates to the top-flight English league, so that would be Division One (the First Division) pre-1992.

One reason often cited for the poor performance of the English national football (soccer) team is that the club sides play the predictable 4-4-2 formation and this isn't effective at the international level.  So often the England national team plays a variation of this, 4-3-3 for example, but as the players are not used to it this gets used as an excuse, rightly or wrongly, for their underperforming.

Wikipedia has a lot of information on this topic and you can see 4-4-2 has been popular in many countries until recently: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_(association_football)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_%28association_football%29).

Liverpool (for one) are still using the 4-4-2 formation and dominated English football especially in the 1980s; here's another interesting link: http://thebeaveronline.co.uk/2012/03/15/the-death-of-the-4-4-2/. (If the URL worries you, it is about soccer, I promise!)

Comment: Since the start of the 2012-13 season Liverpool have played more 4-3-3 than 4-4-2.

Answer (score 2):

I think it was the 4-4-2. it had slighter modification like 4-1-2-1-2 and 4-2-2-2.
4-3-3 was used in attacking situations when in search of plenty of goals. 4-2-2 was more of a normal formation. 
Wingers were the most important part of English football strategy. in 4-3-3 there is no Wingers and therefore not very widely used in EPL

Answer (score 1):

Echoing what everyone else has said but 4-4-2 is probably the most commonly used formation since the Premier League was founded in 1992. Since the influx of overseas players over the past few seasons the 4-2-3-1 is becoming quite popular with Chelsea and Arsenal both favouring this system.

Chelsea playing with Oscar, Hazard and Willian as the 3, and one of Torres/Ba/Schurrle as the lone striker. Similarly, Arsenal play with Ramsey, Ozil and Rosicky/Oxlade-Chamberlain, with Giroud/Podolski upfront.

This style is becoming increasingly attractive to watch as opposed to the rigid 4-4-2.